# Can get data on editing part <br /><b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: row in

Tags: php, html

I am new in PHP. I keep on getting "undefined variable row in". I already read and try suggestion from other related question and answer here but nothing works for me.

**PHP code**

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 require_once('dbConfig.php');
if(isset($_GET['ass_id'])){
    $ass_id = $_GET['ass_id'];
    $sql = "select * from beedass where ass_id=".$ass_id;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }else{
        $errorMsg = 'Could not select a record';
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])){
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];


    if(empty($subject)){
        $errorMsg = 'Please input subject course';
    }elseif(empty($date)){
        $errorMsg = 'Please input date to be passed';
    }elseif(empty($content)){
        $errorMsg = 'Please input assignment content';
    }


    //check upload file not error than insert data to database
    if(!isset($errorMsg)){
        $sql = "update beedass
                                set subject = '".$subejct."',
                                    date = '".$date."',
                                    content = '".$content."'
                where ass_id=".$ass_id;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if($result){
            $successMsg = 'New record updated successfully';
            header('refresh:5;view_beedass.php');
        }else{
            $errorMsg = 'Error '.mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }

  }
 ?>
```

Keep on getting error on this line on my HTML code:

```
 <form action="edit_beedass.php?ass_id=<?php echo $row['ass_id'];?>" 
 method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-2">Subject Course</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" value="<?
 php echo $row['subject'] ; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="position" class="col-md-2">Date and Time to be 
 Passed</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" value="<?php 
 echo (isset($row['date']))? $row['date'] : $date ; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="position" class="col-md-2">Assignment Content</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="content" class="form-control" value="<?
 php echo (isset($row['content'])) ; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
```

The error I get is undefined variable row in echo $row['subject'], echo $row['date'] and echo $row['content'].

Comment: it happens because no rows are fetched

Comment: <?php
 session_start();
 require_once('dbConfig.php');
if(isset($_GET['ass_id'])){
    $ass_id = $_GET['ass_id'];
    $sql = "select * from beedass where ass_id=".$ass_id;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }else{
        $errorMsg = 'Could not select a record';
    }
}

Comment: in this line of my code?

Comment: try die(“Couldn’t select a record “) instead of $errorMsg = “Couldn’t select a record “).

Comment: can you give an idea how to fetched the data from database so i can able to update it.

Comment: it give's me syntax error result

Comment: try this ‘ $sql = “SELECT * FROM beedass WHERE ass_id=‘$ass_id’”; ‘

Comment: also you need the data in your database to get the data.. else you should check the existence of $row before printing them out

Comment: try your $row statements as ‘ echo isset($row[“your key”]) ? $row[“your key”] : “”; ‘

Comment: the result is null

Comment: try adding a few code to your mysqi_query as ‘ $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(“coulnot fetch data”) ‘ this approach is strictly for debugging purpose. please dont use this in a production website unless you need it

Comment: same null result

Comment: you may also use die(mysqli_error($conn))

Comment: still null result

Comment: are you using ?ass_id=<your id> in your url?

Comment: yes. on my last form before this form I include on my header location code the ?ass_id=.$ass_id, which is my primary key

Comment: can you type this at the top of your code and show the result?? ‘ var_dump($_GET); die(); ‘

Comment: this is the result - array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" }

Comment: I think you are passing `id` as the get parameter and checking for `ass_id` in `$_GET`,
You should be using `$_GET["id"]`

Comment: in this form of my code? I already change it all from id to ass_id

Comment: If you had changed the `id` to `ass_id` then you should not be expecting a result like `array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" }` when you `var_dump($_GET)`

Comment: i provided all my code in this form. and on my php code it is written as "ass_id"

Comment: can you please verify that your code has `?ass_id` or `?id` in the previous page that you have mentioned before?

Comment: i checked it again and this now the result of var_dump - array(1) { ["ass_id"]=> string(1) "5" }

Comment: So now you should be getting the results.

Comment: the result is couldn't select data why? what is wrong on my code?

Comment: cause 1 : You don't have the data in your database.
cause 2 : You are connected to a wrong database.
cause 3 : sometimes it can be caused because of not escaping the query. that is you have to use code like "SELECT * FROM \`tablename\` WHERE \`col1\`='data1'"

Comment: Thank God it is solve now. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: happy to help you

Comment: You are really a big help. I can now proceed on my next form. hope you can still help me on my future problem. Thanks a lot.